# onsubmit verify that all functions return true

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i have about 6 form inputs that i have javascript running validation on, how would i go about verifying that all functions return as true? here are two samples of my javascript functions

```
$(document).ready(function() {

//First Name Input Field
$( "#first_name" ).focusout(function() {
    if( this.value === "" || this.value === null ) {
        $( "#error_messages" ).text("First Name* is required so my response won't go to spam");
        return false;
    } else {
        var re = /^[A-Za-z-]+$/;
        if(re.test(document.getElementById("first_name").value)) {
            $( "#error_messages" ).text("");
            return true;
        } else {
            $( "#error_messages" ).text("First Name* not a valid name");
            return false;
        }
    }
});

//Last Name Input Field
$( "#last_name" ).focusout(function() {
    if( this.value === "" || this.value === null ) {
        $( "#error_messages" ).text("Last Name* is required so my response won't go to spam");
        return false;
    } else {
        var re = /^[A-Za-z-]+$/;
        if(re.test(document.getElementById("last_name").value)) {
            $( "#error_messages" ).text("");
            return true;
        } else {
            $( "#error_messages" ).text("Last Name* not a valid name");
            return false;
        }
    }
});
});
```

Comment: You can assign the return values to variables, firstNameValid and lastNameValid for example, and on form submit you can check if these are all true

Comment: so rather than return true or return false i could create global variables and assign values to them from within the functions?

Comment: Yes, this could be a possible solution.

Comment: Its simple... for suppose u have two fields fistname and lastname.. define two veriable firstnamestatus and lastnamestatus as true.... if error overwrite them as false. Where u use return false

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add default variables and set as true.
And when error occurred overwrite the value as false.

Idea is that:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {

    var firstnameStatus = true;
    var lastnameStatus = true;

    if(firstname have error){
   // your code
   var firstnameStatus = false;
}

if(lastname have error){
   // your code
   var lastnameStatus = false;
}

    if( firstnameStatus == true && lastnameStatus == true){
    alert('all fields true');
    }

    });
```